# If I asked a villager to move in before I built Nook’s Cranny, will they still come?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I invited Zucker to move in before I built Nook’s Cranny and when I placed the home plots, they didn’t say sold so will he still come? I invited Skye too.

Comment: The pronouns are a bit ambiguous. Who is 'he'?

Comment: I had some villagers invited before plots were built who eventually joined, but I didn't check if the plots were marked as "sold" or not, so I won't answer officially.